# Upload image to meta ads using marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to upload an image, get the image hash for use in creating an adcreative using meta marketing api on google colab, but i keep getting an empty list, don't know why that keeps happening.

i have properly authenticated and i am able to post ad campaigns, adsets remotely but i am unable to upload and image or view list of existing images/hash

```
path = '/content/drive/Shareddrives/Design/sampleimage.png'
image = AdImage('act_5**********')

image[AdImage.Field.filename] = path
image.remote_create()
image_hash = image[AdImage.Field.hash]
print(image)
```

even when i try to read the existing adimages i also get an empty lsit.

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)
my_account = AdAccount('act_5**********')
fields = ['id','hash','name','original_height','original_width']

images = my_account.get_ad_images(fields=fields)
images
```

Answer (score -1):

try uploading your images as  .bmp, .jpeg, or .gif: